# iptables rule to stop DDOS

Tags: security, iptables, ddos

My server is undergoing a ddos attack with the traffic in my apache logs appearing like:

```
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:04 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
ip address - - [11/Apr/2013:01:01:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 416 31 "-" "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
```

How can I block this with IP Tables?  I am using:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j DROP
```

but that doesn't appear to be doing anything.  I think i need something along this line though.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you can do this in iptables, but I'd recommend you to have a look at OSSEC, which blocks repeated offenders automatically. You can also have a look at CloudFare, they also have a free package and are specialized at DDoS mitigation, as what you need to do is drop the traffic *before* it reaches you. If the address is just one IP address I would just drop it permanently.

I changed an iptable rule from [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187), have a look:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent   --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
```

Comment: as i block the ip addresses, the traffic continues from new ones.  i think they are spoofing the return address.  i'll check out OSSEC and let you know.

Comment: If they are spoofing the address, you need to get a service that scrubs the packets before they reach you. You can't mitigate this with iptables if they are spoofing the IPs.

Comment: not even with ratelimit?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your iptables and some analysis showing that the rate does exceed the limits you specified it's impossible to say why this is happenning - for example, it may simply be that that you're getting lots of requests across a single connection.

Even if you are not using keepalives, a stateful firewall (on its own) is not a very effective tool for precenting DOS attacks. Traffic shaping helps - but this gets very complicated very quickly. There are some apache modules which support minimum bandwidth guarantee - which is a lot simpler to configure than kernel QOS. But I would recommend using fail2ban to block the IP addresses causing the problem.

Comment: would it help if we set the limit to 2/sec?  you can see from the traffic above that more than 2 per second are flying in.  a stateful firewall is all i have at this point. i'll check out fail2ban, and let you know

Comment: You'll likely break your legitimate traffic with 2/s

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. Using a stateful firewall against dDoS is often a bad idea: you help the attacker by allowing him to allocate state (therefore memory) on your machine. The state module should be replaced by simply something like `--tcp-flags SYN SYN`
2. The `-j DROP` at the end is an error, it means to drop all the packets that are below the thershold. It should be `-j ACCEPT` and have a DROP rule afterwards. (If you saw no effect, it may be because you have another ACCEPT rule later, or a general ACCEPT policy.)
3. I prefer the hashlimit module, which can works with prefixes, not just individual IP addresses `--tcp-flags SYN SYN -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name Web --hashlimit-above 3/second --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-burst 7 --hashlimit-srcmask 28 -j DROP`

Comment: i tried this:  iptables -A droplist -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN SYN -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name badguys --hashlimit-above 3/second --hashlimit-burst 7 --hashlimit-srcmask 28 -j DROP  and it completely blocked me out of my box.  any ideas?

Comment: It all depends on your default policy. May be it is DROP?